# Facebook Authentication for Mobile over ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to add facebook authentication for mobile on ASP.NET Boilerplate project. I do everything as mentioned [here](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Core#social-logins).  Found similar discussion on [forum](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=11087#p11074). But despite, I do everything like on doc and forums, I got no result from GetExternalAuthenticationProviders and ExternalAuthenticate give error **"Unknown external auth provider: Facebook"**. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: check you have made ` "Authentication": {
    "Facebook": {
      "IsEnabled": "true",`

Comment: I guess you are using Asp.Net Zero... you can ask it on the forum https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com ...

Comment: @viveknuna I had done it but did not help.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu I use the free version of ASP.NET Boilerplate. Is it activated for the free version? I could not post a question to the forum. Have I to purchase for it?

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu I check from the github repo that [https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/IdentityServerDemo](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/IdentityServerDemo)  for the not updated version it works. But for the updated version to 3.4.0 it is not working.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu for the previous version there have been implemented [FacebookAuthProviderApi](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/IdentityServerDemo/src/IdentityServerDemo.Web.Core/Authentication/External/Facebook/FacebookAuthProviderApi.cs). For newer version also we have to implement similar ProviderApi? New samples do not include ProviderApi examples. Could you please help

Comment: facebook auth is a paid feature exists in Asp.Net Zero. For aspnetboilerplate you need to implement it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Social Login in ASP.NET Boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808179/how-to-setup-social-login-in-asp-net-boilerplate)